# I am not able to mute product delete ability on permission set group

Tags: permission-sets, permission-set-groups

I want to mute delete ability on my permission set group for the product object but cannot do that due to the error you see on the screenshot. Error itself doesnt make any sense since it says that I have to first mute Modify All Records but there is no such option on product object. Can anybody help me with that?

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and opened a case with SF. This is a known issue with Product, Pricebook, and Idea objects. See [the known issues article here](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000uYesC/unable-to-mute-edit-and-delete-on-permission-set-group-due-to-absence-of-modify-all-option). Allegedly, the product team is working on this. In the mean time multiple permission sets need to be created.